# Gradle: Adding sources.jar file within /lib folder of published dist.zip along with all my other dependencies

Tags: java, maven, jar, gradle

I have a java project that I am building using gradle. I am releasing a dist.zip folder for my project and I want to add the sources.jar for my project to the /lib subfolder within dist.zip. I am able to create a sources.jar file along with my dist.zip file but I am not sure how to add the sources.jar within the dist.zip. How can I do this? I've tried to copy the .jar into the /lib folder after creating it but I am unable to get it to work. Below is my publishing and sourcesJar task within my gradle.build script.

```
task sourcesJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: classes) {
    classifier = 'sources'
    from sourceSets.main.allSource
}

publishing {

    repositories {  
        maven {
            url 'localfolder'
        }
    }

    publications {

        maven(MavenPublication) {
            groupId 'ca.project'
            artifactId applicationName
            version version

            from components.java

            artifact sourcesJar {
                classifier "sources"
            }

            artifact distZip {
                classifier "dist"
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to tell the [application plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html) to include the output of your `sourcesJar` task in the distribution:

```
distributions {
    main {
        contents {
            from sourcesJar
        }
    }
}
```

That will place it in the root, if you want it somewhere else you can do this:

```
distributions {
    main {
        contents {
            from(sourcesJar) {
                into "lib"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Good, perhaps you can [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) my answer then? =)